# Grails: Data is updated when try to sort a list

Tags: grails

I have been facing a situation where following code block has been behaving in a strange manner. In following code snippet, when I am trying to sort activity list of case work flow in my taglib, it perform db update instead of just sorting the data out. It updates the version of the workflow row. 
Can you please suggest me where I am missing anything? 
Quick help will highly be appreciated.

TagLib:

```
class CaseFormTagLib { 
     static namespace = 'caseform' 

    def caseForm = { attr, body -> 
            def caseWorkflow = CaseWorkflow.read(attr.workflowId) 

            //Line causing issue
            def activityList = caseWorkflow?.sortedActivityList  
    } 
}
```

Domain:

```
class CaseWorkflow { 
    List caseActivityList 
    static hasMany = [caseActivityList: CaseActivity] 

    @Transient 
    def getSortedActivityList(){ 
            Collections.sort(this.caseActivityList) 
            return this.caseActivityList 

    } 
} 

class CaseActivity implements Comparable { 
    /** 
     * Activity Id 
     */ 
    Integer activityId 

    @Override 
    public int compareTo(obj) { 
            if(!obj || !obj.activityId) { 
                    return 1 
            } else if (!this.activityId) { 
                    return -1 
            } else { 
                    return this.activityId.compareTo(obj.activityId) 
            } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is because of [`read()`](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/read.html) that is being used in the taglib. `read()` does not `flush` the domain to database automatically unless there is a change to its associations.

In this case, since you are sorting the associations, a dirty check is done on the 
associations and finally the object is automatically flushed. Read through description from the link above, mainly:

> There is one exception to this though - any associated collections,
>   for example an Author's books collection, will participate in
>   automatic flushing and dirty detection. This is because mapped
>   collections are treated differently than regular properties and they
>   manage their own dirty checking independent of the containing domain
>   class.

Moreover, by default associations is a `Set` in domain class. If you want the associations to be sorted always then you can make them `SortedSet` making `Comparable` would work the same way you have defined for `CaseActivity` :

```
class CaseWorkflow { 
    SortedSet caseActivityList 
    static hasMany = [caseActivityList: CaseActivity] 
}
```

Is it mandatory to have it indexed by using a `List`?